# How to open a blob:url in a HTML5 Video

Tags: html, html5-video

So I wanted to add an HTML5 Video object from another website to my website. On some websites, I can just copy the URL from the src but on some, I can't - because of the blob. I tried to copy the whole object but it shows nothing on my website. I tried this on a website which gives you access to a lot of TV channels and movies (legally) and I noticed that they used a classic HTML5 Video player so I thought I could just embed it to my website. I did this on other websites - I could even just left click on the video object and click on "Open video in new tab" and I could copy the video object from there. But on this website that option is faded out but there is a "Cast" option. Here is the video object from the website:

```
<video data-v-6c3a6820="" id="player" width="1366" height="768" crossorigin="anonymus" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" data-viblast-key="d6293ad219a4af6550b20f07e66451d72d53c9a3ca77413f2eb2bd3c0b947827df882f2913d340fb42195b89764dd8db49ffb3ba29d41708" data-viblast-src="https://sbb-bg-ku-h1-35.ug-be.cdn.united.cloud/stream?i=dBYjXstwR9iFl6QFDTk5RA&amp;a=4IfyeulCQOI0ox6iM05xTU7I77AJV196e3vMhwvZao19ijsvI0wc_g8lAYTyZuZYqiRxSiyFAntLl91PHmdZsc9NJVntuPghZ5s03ktRfMlpV7Gv3YPbDXNz-DKEMMems9PkKqRKugkDdnj8bcZSCcpMSWFyYCyXkI_ZIpikT6reNFualp09uiT5dQQlbCKd1C8mWxOAo6tF9pTYVC2hVckzX4cni5rj2-Kh7taIT7zAOEHIiRW4GnldTY83w5aOxMpSfY00pD9SX0xmyxMyW_9HUsecpBSX3s1kt-v9ekiQddiO2D98DwklA3OVLkDlE36YNLr1zoQR21ilMLes4jz70Ti9ycUJs4jaOE2w9kuKzixbx6_oH5nqXsebppWc&amp;sp=sbb&amp;u=2kfu9hq2ibxxyxr&amp;player=m3u8v&amp;session=ebcae820-2cd6-45be-92ef-1e5b6c6ee6a5" src="blob:https://eon.tv/01051a85-367f-4ca0-9b53-03c615f8436e"><p data-v-6c3a6820="" class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a data-v-6c3a6820="" href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p></video>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Blob URL comes from JavaScript and is most likely a source using MediaSource Extensions.  JavaScript can retrieve the video (usually in DASH or HLS format) and append content while the video tag is playing it back.

You should look at your network tab in your developer tools to find the DASH manifest URL or HLS playlist URL.

Comment: I checked the Network tab and played the video but everything I see is random text and when I click on them they will open an error page or start some download of some file.

Comment: Look for something with the `Content-Type` response header of `application/dash+xml`, or `application/vnd.apple.mpegurl`.

Comment: There's nothing.

Comment: @andrewly3 Perhaps you should share the actual site.  There's definitely *something* somewhere.